# How to send/receive binary data through sockets?

Tags: c, linux, ftp, encode, ftp-server

I have to code a FTP server and I have a problem on how data is transferred.

I'm using **ftp** command on linux to test it and I'm currently working on `LIST`, which sends the list of files/directories in the working directory. Everything works fine (ftp well prints the list of files) except that **ftp** prints the following warning:

```
WARNING! 5 bare linefeeds received in ASCII mode
File may not have transferred correctly.
```

I would like to remove that warning, I think **ftp** is expecting binary data but I don't know how to send data like that through socket, I'm currently doing the most basic way to send `ls` result:

```
dup2(dst_channel, 1);
execlp("ls", "ls", "-l", NULL);
```

Comment: FTP is expecting line breaks to be CR-LF, but you're just sending LF.

Comment: Is there a way to change that without having to read the result of the command `ls` and replace every LF by CR-LF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTP protocol specifies that the `LIST` command should send its result in NETASCII, which means that newlines are represented as CRLF. But standard Linux programs output just LF for newlines.

You need to run the `ls` command with its output connected to a pipe. Your server reads from the pipe, replaces any `\n` characters with `\r\n', and writes this to the socket.

You'll need to do something similar when transferring actual files, except when the client requests binary mode.

Comment: An alternative is to implement your own `ls` code that outputs in the format FTP expects. You'll need to do this if you want to implement the `MLSD` command in RFC 3659.